# How to store (stream) a TColor array property?

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I'm writing a non-windowed VCL control that contains a `TColor` array property, called `Colors[]`. The `Colors[]` property can be used to set the color of different parts of the control at run-time. The control will also get a property editor to set the `Colors[]` property at design-time.

I know how to store array properties, but I've never done this for `TColor` values. Normally, `TColor` properties are stored as either a color constant (e.g. `clBlack` or `clWindowText`) or a numeric value (for custom colors).

`TReader` and `TWriter` have methods to read and write integers and strings, but not `TColor` values. I looked at the source code of `TPersistent`, but couldn't find how it reads and writes `TColor` values.

Here's an abstract of my code:

```
class TMyControl : public TGraphicControl
{
    typedef TGraphicControl inherited;

    private:
        TColor* FColors;
        int FCount;

        TColor __fastcall GetColors (int Index);
        void __fastcall SetColors (int Index, TColor Value);
        void __fastcall ReadColors (TReader* Reader);
        void __fastcall WriteColors (TWriter* Writer);
        void __fastcall SetCount (int Value);

        void __fastcall CMColorChanged (TMessage &Msg);

    protected:
        virtual void __fastcall DefineProperties (TFiler *Filer);

    public:
        __fastcall TMyControl (TComponent *Owner);
        __fastcall ~TMyControl ();

        __property TColor Colors[int Index] = {read=GetColors, write=SetColors};

    __published:
        __property Color;

        __property int Count = {read=FCount, write=SetCount, default=1};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(CM_COLORCHANGED, TMessage, CMColorChanged)
END_MESSAGE_MAP(inherited)
};


void ModifyExtents (TColor* &Array, int NewSize, TColor Default)
{
    // Allocates/resizes 'Array' to contain 'NewSize' elements and initializes new elements with 'Default'.
}

__fastcall TMyControl::TMyControl (TComponent *Owner) : inherited(Owner)
{
}

__fastcall TMyControl::~TMyControl ()
{
    delete[] FColors;
}

TColor __fastcall TMyControl::GetColors (int Index)
{
    if (Index < 0 || Index >= FCount)
        throw Exception(SIndexOutOfRange);

    return(FColors ? FColors[Index] : Color);
}

void __fastcall TMyControl::SetColors (int Index, TColor Value)
{
    if (Index < 0 || Index >= FCount)
        throw Exception(SIndexOutOfRange);

    if (!FColors)
        ModifyExtents(FColors, FCount, Color);

    if (FColors[Index] != Value)
    {
        FColors[Index] = Value;

        Invalidate();
    }
}

void __fastcall TMyControl::SetCount (int Value)
{
    if (Value < 0)
        Value = 0;

    if (FCount != Value)
    {
        if (FColors)
            ModifyExtents(FColors, Value, Color);

        FCount = Value;

        Invalidate();
    }
}

void __fastcall TMyControl::CMColorChanged (TMessage &Msg)
{
    inherited::Dispatch(&Msg);

    if (FColors)
    {
        delete[] FColors;
        FColors = NULL;
    }
}

void __fastcall TMyControl::DefineProperties (TFiler* Filer)
{
    inherited::DefineProperties(Filer);

    Filer->DefineProperty("Colors", ReadColors, WriteColors, (FColors != NULL));
}

void __fastcall TMyControl::ReadColors (TReader* Reader)
{
    Reader->ReadListBegin();

    for (int i = 0; i < FCount; i++)
        Colors[i] = Reader->Read...();  // ReadInteger, ReadString, ...?

    Reader->ReadListEnd();
}

void __fastcall TMyControl::WriteColors (TWriter* Writer)
{
    Writer->WriteListBegin();

    for (int i = 0; i < FCount; i++)
        Writer->Write...(Colors[i]);    // WriteInteger, WriteString, ...?

    Writer->WriteListEnd();
}
```

The `Count` property specifies the number of different parts in the control, which is also the number of `TColor` values stored in the `FColors` array. The `FColors` array is only allocated when the `Colors[]` property is written to. If the `FColors` array doesn't exist, reading the `Colors[]` property returns the value of the control's `Color` property. Setting the control's `Color` property destroys the `FColors` array.

How do I read and write `TColor` values, so that color constants are preserved (and not converted to numeric values)?

Comment: `TColor` is just an integer, so use `(Read|Write)Integer()` unless you want their registered names to appear in the DFM stream in which case you will have to translate each value back and forth. Or, you can just write the entire array as a binary blob, since that is what it really is in memory.

Comment: Alternatively, you might think about changing your design to use a `__published` `TCollection` w/ `TCollectionItem` for each color, instead of using a `TColor[]` array. That way, the DFM streaming system can handle all of the `TColor` elements for you without you having to write any streaming code at all, and you gain full design-time support to configure your colors in the Object Inspector. You can optionally keep your array property and have its getter/setter access the `TCollection`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the tip on using a `TCollection`, I will look into that. The idea was to keep the registered names in the DFM stream. I can use `ColorToIdent()` to obtain the registered name if there is one and `IdentToColor()` to convert the registered name to a `TColor` value. I can read/write numeric color values using `(Read|Write)Integer()`. How do I write the registered names? `WriteString` outputs quotes into the DFM stream. Also, how do I read the color values when they can either be an integer or a registered name?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I can use `(Read|Write)Ident()` for the registered color names. But how do I determine which `Read...()` method to use when reading the DFM stream?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Never mind, I found `TReader::NextValue()`. See the update to my question. Thanks for your input, Remy.

Comment: Your update did not belong as an edit to the question. I have moved it into your answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TReader::NextValue()` returns the value type without incrementing the position in the DFM stream. The return value is used to differentiate between an identifier (registered color name) and an integer value (custom color).

The `ReadColors()` and `WriteColors()` methods thus become:

```
void __fastcall TMyControl::ReadColors (TReader* Reader)
{
    Reader->ReadListBegin();

    for (int i = 0; i < FCount; i++)
    {
        switch (Reader->NextValue())
        {
            case vaInt8:
            case vaInt16:
            case vaInt32:
                Colors[i] = TColor(Reader->ReadInteger());
                break;

            case vaIdent:
            {
                int Value;

                if (IdentToColor(Reader->ReadIdent(), Value))
                {
                    Colors[i] = TColor(Value);
                    break;
                }
            }

            default:
                // Alternative: throw EReadError(SInvalidPropertyValue);
                Reader->SkipValue();
        }
    }

    Reader->ReadListEnd();
}

void __fastcall TMyControl::WriteColors (TWriter* Writer)
{
    Writer->WriteListBegin();

    for (int i = 0; i < FItemCount; i++)
    {
        String S;

        if (ColorToIdent(Colors[i], S))
            Writer->WriteIdent(S);
        else
            Writer->WriteInteger(Colors[i]);
    }

    Writer->WriteListEnd();
}
```

As an alternative to `TReader::SkipValue()`, you can also throw an exception in case you encounter a value type other than an integer or an identifier.